# How to output attributes of inner objects in "fields"?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have indexed a document such as:

```
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Station",
    "city": "Seattle"
  }
}
```

I can query and extract `name` by using:

```
"fields" : [
  "name"
]
```

which returns:

```
"fields" : {
  "name" : [
    "Alice"
  ]
}
```

How do I extract `city` too as a field called `"address.city"`?

I have tried:

```
"fields" : [
    "name",
    "address.city"
]
```

and

```
"fields" : [
    "name",
    "address['city']"
]
```

but they don't produce any output.

Note:

- I have read-only access; I can't `PUT` calculated fields.
- I can't use [`"runtime_mappings"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-search-request.html) - the version I'm using doesn't support it (zero chance of upgrading)

Comment: ```PUT user/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Station",
    "city": "Seattle"
  }
}

GET user/_search
{
  "fields": [
    "name",
    "address.city"
  ]
}``` the extraction referencing `address.city` shall work ideally. Could you update your question with the relevant index mapping if you are able to read it? Also, what one might be interested in would be the version of Elasticsearch in use. On the other hand, much better way of only extracting few source attributes would be `"_source": {
    "includes": ["name","address.city"]
  }`

Comment: @Naman thanks. `"_source": { "includes": ["name","address.city"] }` and `"fields": ["name", "address.city"] }` worked! Please post as an answer and I will accept it! Actually, just `"_source"` is enough

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to not be able to find a relevant duplicate Q&A for this. But it is as simple as combining the concepts of accessing inner attributes with field extraction.

You can make use of the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering) in your search:

```
"fields": ["name", "address.city"]
OR
"_source": { "includes": ["name", "address.city"] }
OR
"_source": ["name", "address.city"]
```

For an example:

```
PUT user/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Station",
    "city": "Seattle"
  }
}

GET user/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["name","address.city"]
  }
}
```

Would result in:

```
 ... "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "user",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Alice",
          "address": {
            "city": "Seattle"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What I want is `"address.city" : "Seattle"` , which is more or less what I get if I also specify `"fields": ["name", "address.city"]` which returns ` "fields" : { "name" : [ "name" ], "address.city" : [ "Seattle" ] }`, which solves my problem.